# Implementing Cloud of Communities using Linked List

Tags: c, arrays, arraylist, linked-list

Recently I came across a question, I had to code it but failed to do so effectively. So i'll try to explain the question in the best way I can, and it goes like..

There are different people belonging to different communities. Say for example, 1 belongs to C1, 2 belong to C2 and 3 belongs to C3. We can perform two operations, Query and Join. Query returns the total number of people belonging to the person's community. And Join is used to combine the communities of exactly two persons into one.
We are taking the number of people and the number of operations to be performed as an input and we need to produce the result onto the standard output.

```
Example Case: (Q -> Query and J -> Join)
3 // No. of People
6 // No. of Operations
Q 1 // Prints 1
J 1,2 // Joins communities of 1 and 2
Q 1 // Prints 2
J 2,3 // Joins communities of 1 and 2
Q 3 // Prints 3
Q 1 // Prints 3
```

So essentially, its like people are belonging to individual bubbles initially and on join, we join the bubbles of two peoples to form a larger bubble containing two people.
There are different ways to solve this problem. Using ArrayList methods of Java, its pretty easy. I was trying to solve it using arrays.
My approach was to form an array for each person initially and as we join two communities, the respective arrays are added with the people as described :

```
Arr1 : 1 // Array for Person 1 ; Size 1
Arr2 : 2 // Array for Person 2 ; Size 1
J 1,2 results in,
Arr1 : 1,2 // Size 2
Arr2 : 2,1 // Size 2
```

But I was told that this is not an effective approach, an effective approach would be to make use of Linked List. I was unable to use linked list to solve it. So I would like some inputs from you guys on the approach, how exactly do I make use of Linked List to keep track of Join operations?

Sorry for the long post, and thanks in advance :)

P.S : I am not sure if the title is appropriate, kindly suggest proper title in case its not appropriate.

Comment: I did not read every detail, but that might be a job for (bit)sets. If you have no more than 64 communities, a `unsigned long long` would be sufficient, otherwise you had to write your own operations.

Comment: I forgot to mention, to keep things simple we can only take a maximum of 10 persons as input.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why somebody felt that linked lists would be better than arrays in this instance, but joining the communities is as simple as adding all of the members of one to the other, and changing all the pointers that point to the now empty community to point to the node containing all of the members. Query should be simple enough that it goes without saying.

Comment: This should better be a comment, not an answer.